# Как слушать UDP ip-port?

Tags: c#, udp

В Консоли нужно выбрать `ip/port` и слушать его на активное соединения, после отправить пару байтов на выбранный `ip/port` и возвратить кто посылал ответ от кому послали)

Как правильно юзать UDP socket ?

Answer (score 3):

Ключевая фраза для поиска в гугле "C# UDP echo server". Вот, к примеру, хорошее описание - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552497/Scalable-UDP-Client-Server

Код оттуда

создать сокет

```
_UdpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
```

"забиндить" (привязать к адресу/порту)

```
_UdpSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Int32.Parse(
   SPConfigVal.GetConfigValue(SecurePassConstants.ServerPort))));

_UdpSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(_ReceiveByteData, 0, _ReceiveByteData.Length,
SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, _UdpSocket);
```

и теперь в DoReceiveFrom будут прилетать данные.

а дальше только читать/отправлять

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, связь использования между обычным компьютером, и через интернет ( как связаться с другим пк и переслать ему какой-нибудь текст). И самое главное `NAT`, по сути мы должны присвоить ip и порт одинаковый ( открытый ) как в клиенте, так и на сервере?. Обновил ответ!

Comment: не нужно "обновлять вопрос", если он стал другим. В этом случае ответ выглядит немного странным. Если есть новый вопрос - лучше его явно и задать. Это бесплатно и просто. (и хорошо бы вернуть вопрос к начальному состоянию)

Answer (score 0):

Ниже способ между собой, а как через интернет реализовать?

**Клиент:**

```
private static void connect(int x, int y)
{
   UdpClient client = new UdpClient("127.0.0.1", 1200);
   string ch = "X: " + x.ToString() + " Y:" + y.ToString();
   byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ch);
   client.Send(data, data.Length);
// client.Close();
}
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   connect(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

**Сервер:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1200);
        UdpClient server = new UdpClient(ip);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("[UDP - MouseContoller] - Listening!");
        while (true)
        {
          byte[] data = server.Receive(ref ip);
          string ch = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
          Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
          Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] " +ch + " ");
        }
    }

}
```